# AngularJs - ng-repeat collection of collection in td of table

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Via AngularJS (ng-repeat), I would use a list of list on the td of html table.

**datas in controller:**

```
$scope.schedules = [{plage:'8-12'},{plage:'14-18'},{plage:'19-23'}];
$scope.days = [{day:'Monday',schedules:$scope.schedules},{day:'Tuesday',schedules:$scope.schedules},{day:'Wednesday',schedules:$scope.schedules},{day:'Thursday',schedules:$scope.schedules},{day:'Friday',schedules:$scope.schedules}];
```

**I want 2 lines (1st = days and 2nd = schedules):**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Days:</td>
    <td colspan="3">Monday</td>
    <td colspan="3">Tuesday</td>
    <td colspan="3">Wednesday</td>
    <td colspan="3">Thursday</td>
    <td colspan="3">Friday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="week">Schedules:</td>
    <td>8-12</td><td>14-18</td><td>19-23</td>
    <td>8-12</td><td>14-18</td><td>19-23</td>
    <td>8-12</td><td>14-18</td><td>19-23</td>
    <td>8-12</td><td>14-18</td><td>19-23</td>
    <td>8-12</td><td>14-18</td><td>19-23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**in HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Days:</td>
        <td ng-repeat="businessWeekDay in days" colspan="3">{{businessWeekDay.day}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Schedule:</td>
        <!-- "businessWeekDay in days" -->
        <!-- "schedule in businessWeekDay.schedules"-->
        <td ng-repeat="?????????????">{{schedule.plage}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `businessWeekDay in businessWeekDays` - shouldn't that be `businessWeekDay in days`?

Comment: Yes, businessWeekDay in days. My case is in directive with scope: {businessWeekDays: '=days'}. I edit my code, sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatten the schedules, and use a single ng-repeat:

```
var allSchedules = [];
$scope.days.forEach(function(day) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(allSchedules, day.schedules);
});
```

And in the view:

```
<td ng-repeat="schedule in allSchedules">{{ schedule.plage }}</td>
```